# How to learn stored procedures in SQL Server as a Java programmer?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

What is a good way to learn to develop SQL Server(2005) stored procedures? I am primarily a java developer but need to take on SQL Server stored procedure development. I have some basic SQL in my background but nothing major. Any good specific tutorials maybe using the adventure works schema? Or just good reference sites that contain alot of useful syntax.

I would say either the abundance of good resources or a very useful couple tutorials will be the winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally there are two ways that I have found to get up to speed quickly.

1. Have real world problems that you need to solve.
2. Get a good T-SQL Book.  There are numbers of them out there, most of the Microsoft Press ones are good, along with many others.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you're trying to do really.  A good knowledge of SQL is the main requirement.  Above that learn about parameters.

I find most people don't put too much logic in SPs these days.  Rather they're just a collection of standard SQL statements using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just searching for SQL syntax on the internet has pretty much asnwered any question I've had. If nothing else you can always buy a reference book. I have Transact Sql programming by O'Reilly.

Plus, stored procedures are really just

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PROC_NAME]
AS
BEGIN
--ENTER YOUR SQL CODE HERE
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I always start with MSDN for Microsoft products.In most of the case they are good.

And there is nothing much specific to learn from Java side for MSSQL SPs as they are seperate entities existing in DB except invoking it from front end.

I would start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792.aspx).